# How do I show a menu only on a certain section in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using Wordpress 3.2.1 to develop a site.  I have a custom menu that I have created using the internal Appearance Menu.

I'd like this menu to only appear on the Parent, Child, and Ancestor pages of its section.

I'm currently using a long workaround where I'm specifying the individual page numbers of the pages that I want it to appear:

```
                            <?php if( is_page(array(11,354,304,302,297,232,319,317,311,309)) ) :?>
                                <? wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main-about' )); ?>
                            <?php endif;?>
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

no there is not. It just hurts the appearance of the code anyway (y).

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
if( is_page() && ($post->post_parent== 11) )
```